# Xpages, Inherited documents in view panel by using @Unique

Tags: xpages

I have two forms project(Document) and comment(Response to Response) I want to create a view that displays all comments of selected Project

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love doing this type of stuff in xPages.

For a moment, don't think about project and response. Think uniqueID. In order to make the project document reference the comment you add a unique ID to each of them that will reference each other. Don't use response docs in xPages, there is no need I see. When you save the comment, save the unique ID of the parent document to a field on the comment document by referencing this value where document1 is the datasource of the parent and document3 is the document of the child.

```
   <xp:modifyField name="uid"
        value="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}" 
        var="document3">
    </xp:modifyField>
```

Now that you have a bunch of parent and children docs, you create a categorized view where you are only capturing the comments. Use a view selection formula to exclude the parent form. Make the first column the uniqueID that you previously captured. You now have a view that will keep all the comments categorized by the unique id of the parent.

[image: View Categorized by UID]

Now in the xpage you now need to filter on the key value. You filter by computing the keys to the value of the parent document. Here document1 is the parent.

```
 <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="rejections"
        keys="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}">
    </xp:dominoView>
```

The great thing about doing this is it will work in a viewPanel, dataView, or a repeat control since you are referencing the data not the UI.

If you wanted to do comments of comments there are a couple of approaches but I think they would all have the same structure. If you made it this far start looking at repeat controls they will let you break free of the normal notes views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  


I added LinkKey and cLinkKey fields to the project and comment forms that type of both is Document and created a view with view selection SELECT Form = "Comment"  with the first column categorized and bind to cLinkKey then created a xpage for comment form that has a filed with value of 
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{javascript:document1.getDocument().getUniversalID()}"></xp:inputText> sorry I am really beginner in programming I couldn't understand var ="document3" could you please tell me from where it comes? and where is used parent id (LinkKey) field?

Comment: I am not sure that I bind first view column to cLinkKey is correct How does view categorized with parent id?

Comment: Happy to help. So you have two documents. Parent and Child. In xpages vs Notes you can write to multiple datasources on the same page. So document1 is my parent document and document3 is my child document. THis is because I have multiple datasources on a page. My question for you is how does the comment(child) know which project(parent) you are commenting on in your app? How are you architecting your app to function? Is it a separate page for comments? Also you do not need to have an inputText field in order to save a value you can write the value on an event or button press.

Comment: I have a view that display all projects the project title is as a link when I click on project from this view it opens editable there is a view next to project form that should display all comments(and responses of comments) there is a button on top of this view that I can add new comment to selected project. Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to read the uniqueID of the project document you clicked and write it to the uniqueID field of the comment document that is how a relationship is made between the two documents. If you wanted to you could use another unique value it does not have to be uniqueID. You can use a projectname/number or what I commonly do is use this method to show all documents that are assigned to a person. The 'key' is that a value on the parent document needs to be on the child document.

Answer (score 1):

I moved away from using Parent and response documents in Notes years ago because they were just too much trouble. I also moved away fro using the UNID as the 'link' for several reasons. The first is that the UNID can change (resolve a save/rep conflict) Second archiving is all but impossible because again the UNID changes when the document is copied to another DB. So when I create a 'parent' document I store @Unique into a field I call LinkKey, and store that value in all 'response' documents. When I create the response then I store a new @Unique into a field rLinkKey. This way a response to a response knows it's originator (LinkKey) and it's direct parent (rLinKey). Now you can extend this any number of levels deep fairly easily. 
This worked OK in native Notes with some kludge, but now in XPages with repeat controls the real power comes from nested Repeat Control. Something I have always wanted to do in Notes but was never able to is now a piece of cake. 
The down side is that getDocumentByUNID() is going to be faster that getDocumentByKey(LinkKey, true) but the other advantages far out weigh the unnoticeable time difference (IMHO)