# Table input for view

Tags: datagrid, xpages

I would like to have the user enter order items on my order form as a table where they input the Qty and Prod #.  I've not programmed with that type of field so a blank line would initially display for a new order.  They would type a Qty and an item number in the fields and hit enter.  When they hit enter from either field, what do I program to check the validity of the two fields.  Plus I need the item number to be a drop down/type ahead field.  Does anyone have an example of this type of thing they could send me?  It would be looking at a view in the product catalog db.  Also, after they enter an item to order, that "doc" should get stored/saved and a new blank line should open up.

What type of control do I need to use and should these items be stored in their own form or on the main order document?  Could use some guidance here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The question you have is a little broad but I will make a couple suggestions if I can.

You have the main order doc. Then a repeat control with each item. Filter each item by a uniqueID that allows you to join the main doc to the child docs. Each item should be a separate document. You then need to make the items in the repeat control editable.

There is a lot of things going on here and I think you need to get started somewhere. I think the first step is to do a repeat control with response documents.[Xpages, Inherited documents in view panel by using @Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116822/xpages-inherited-documents-in-view-panel-by-using-unique/27117477#27117477)

Comment: I don't want to use response documents but will store a key on the Item documents that identify it's Order document.  Do I use a Data Table inside a Repeat control or is this getting too complicated.  I want the user to be able to edit the Qty or Item Number on a table that shows all Items ordered up to that point in time.  I'll use the onchange event for both those fields to recognize that both have been entered and calculate the pricing from there and automatically save that Item document.  Then I want a new empty line on the table to display for the user to put in the next one.

Comment: Take a look at the link I sent you again. I specifically say "Don't use response documents". But the way that you setup the different documents you treat them like response documents in a hierarchy. I would use a repeat control as it will give you a lot more control over the data and how it is presented. Each row in this table will be a separate document. Once you get the data to display in a repeat control then you can work on getting the data editable and to save.